# Проблема с переводом строки в профиле, во владке "профиль"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Проблема с переводом строка в профиле (вкладка [профиль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile)):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> visited 262 days, 1 consecutive

перевод:

> В1. посетил 262 дня, 1 последовательный
>
> В2. посещал 262 дня, 1 подряд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод обновлен. Тут еще замечена проблема с длительностью участия, но почему-то это не выделено как проблема в текущем вопросе, а потому пока не исправлено :) В ближайшем времени будет.

Длительность участия также исправлена. Требуется обновление базы и пересборка движка.

Comment: что бросилось в глаза) можно дополнить вопрос указанными проблемами перевода.

Comment: @Alex как хотите. Номинально исправлено и то, и другое. Вопрос в том как и когда оно подхватится.